Spring: api gateway with eureka doesn't register services
I'm building a microservice system. The minimal setup to encounter the problem I'm having consists of an api gateway using spring cloud, a service registry using eureka, and a storage service for API endpoints. Below are my configurations:

api gateway:

server:
  port: 8000

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 10
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: storage-service
          uri: lb://storage-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/storage/**
          filters:
            name: Retry
      configurations: health-check
      retry:
        enabled: true



service registry:

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false

spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry


storage service:

server:
  port: 8282


management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring:
  application:
    name: storage-service


service registry's Application is annotated with @EnableEurekaServer and the other 2 are annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient.
When I startup all three at the same time or when the storage service or api gateway goes down and up again, things work as normal and I can call an api to the gateway and have it route to storage service.
However, when api gateway or storage service goes up before service registry about 30 seconds, although storage service is then still registered to service registry, when I call an api to api gateway, it doesn't go through and instead gives me a warning:
WARN 18426 --- [api-gateway] [or-http-epoll-5] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: storage-service

There are other cases when some services go down and up during deployment that leads to the same issue, but I haven't been able to reproduce them yet. What can I do?
spring boot version: 3.3.2
spring cloud version: 2023.0.3
spring cloud eureka version: 4.1.3 (which uses eureka version 2.0.3)
